# Is there a general form for the hyperbola $\frac1x+\frac1y=-\frac2{37}$?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I know that $\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}-\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$ or $xy=c^2$ or $x^2-y^2=a^2$ represents hyperbola.

But I came across the following equations that according to desmos and wolfram are hyperbola. I wonder what their general form is.

- $\frac1x+\frac1y=-\frac2{37}$ ([wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5B1%2Cx%5D%2BDivide%5B1%2Cy%5D%3D-Divide%5B2%2C37%5D))
- $y=\frac{x-1}{x+1}$ ([wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=y%3DDivide%5B%5C%2840%29x-1%5C%2841%29%2Cx%2B1%5D))

I came across the first equation in a Physics problem and second one on [toppr website](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-point-on-the-hyperbola-yfrac-x1-x1-at-which-the-tangents/&ved=2ahUKEwjQ0e-Omsz6AhVNumMGHViTCZMQFnoECBMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0sTkXaudbPUnTWQFeu67SD) while I was looking up the first one.

Comment: Step 1: Multiply by the denominators.

Comment: The first one is $$(x+37/2)(y+37/2)=(37/2)^2.$$ And an analogous expression for the second one.

Comment: In general, if you can rewrite an equation to show it's equivalent to $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$ for some constants $A, \ldots, F$, and you have $B^2 -  4AC > 0$, then that usually gives a hyperbola (except in some degenerate cases where it gives a union of two lines).

Comment: @DanielSchepler: And in that form, OP's equations are $2xy + 37x + 37y = 0$ and $xy - x + y + 1 = 0$.

Comment: @aarbee: Can you clarify exactly what you're expecting from a "general form"?

Comment: @Dan I wanted to ask how we can say that the given equation is a hyperbola.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was multiplying by the denominators but wasn't reaching anywhere.

@Intelligenti pauca's comment made me reverse engineer the equation, and now I can see how the given equation is a rectangular hyperbola.

$$\frac{y+x}{xy}=-\frac1{18.5}\\\implies18.5x+18.5y+xy=0$$

Adding $(18.5)^2$ on both sides, we get

$$(x+18.5)(y+18.5)=(18.5)^2$$